# Compile Apache 2.4.2 in Solaris 10 in a x86 machine (64bits) errors

Tags: apache, x86-64, solaris-10

I'm having a **hard** time compiling  Apache 2.4.2 in Solaris 10 in a x86 machine (64bits)

I installed all the required programs without problems, but when configuring (or doing make) with apache it explode.

I don't know if the problem is the env vairables. I don't know which one is failing -if this was the case-.

Here is a mini script (ran it with: *source* **script**) to illustrate what I'm doing (**Notice** that I install everything in **/opt** using the *prefix* flag):

```
#!/bin/sh

#Set ENV variables
export LDFLAGS=" -L/usr/sfw/lib -R/usr/sfw/lib -L/usr/X/lib -R/usr/X/lib -L/usr/X11/lib -R/usr/X11/lib -L/usr/ccs/lib -R/usr/ccs/lib "
export PATH=/usr/ccs/bin/amd64/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sfw/bin:/usr/sfw/sbin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:/usr/sfw/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH_64=/usr/lib/64:/usr/sfw/lib/64

export CFLAGS=-m64 -O3
export CPP_FLAGS=-m64 -O3
export CC=cc

#Install OPENSSL
cd /opt/build_src/source_apache_openssl/openssl-1.0.1c
./config --prefix=/opt/openssl-1.0.1c thread shared solaris64-gcc -m32
gmake clean
gmake
gmake install

#Install ARP
cd /opt/build_src/source_apache_openssl/apr-1.4.6
./configure --prefix=/opt/apr-1.4.6 --with-gnu-ld --enable-threads
gmake clean
gmake
gmake install

#Install ARP-UTIL
cd /opt/build_src/source_apache_openssl/apr-util-1.4.1
./configure --prefix=/opt/apr-util-1.4.1 --with-openssl=/opt/openssl-1.0.1c --with-apr=/opt/apr-1.4.6 --with-crypto --enable-threads 
gmake clean
gmake
gmake install

#Instalamos Apache
cd /opt/build_src/source_apache_openssl/httpd-2.4.2   ---- IT FAILS!!!
```

Please, note the env variables. **are they OK???**

Here is what I get as an error, when configuring  (**./configure ...** ) Apache:
    ....
    checking build system type... i386-pc-solaris2.10
    checking host system type... i386-pc-solaris2.10
    checking target system type... i386-pc-solaris2.10

```
Configuring Apache Portable Runtime library ...

checking for APR... yes
  setting CPP to "gcc -E"
  adding "-g" to CFLAGS
  adding "-O2" to CFLAGS
  setting CPPFLAGS to " -DSOLARIS2=10 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -D_REENTRANT -   D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE"

Configuring Apache Portable Runtime Utility library...

checking for APR-util... yes
  adding "-L/opt/openssl-1.0.1c/lib" to LDFLAGS
checking for gcc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... no              (!!!!!)
configure: error: in `/opt/build_src/source_apache_openssl/httpd-2.4.2':  (!!!!!)
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables     (!!!!!)
See `config.log' for more details
```

The **config.log** doesn't say anything relevant -at last for me-, it just list the env variables setted -hundreds!-.

Nevertheless, if i do 'gmake' with that error I get:

```
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
BIO_set_callback                    ab.o
BIO_set_callback_arg                ab.o
BIO_get_callback_arg                ab.o
SSL_CTX_set_info_callback           ab.o
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to ab
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [ab] Error 1
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/build_src/source_apache_openssl/httpd-2.4.2/support'
gmake[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/build_src/source_apache_openssl/httpd-2.4.2/support'
gmake: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

**EDIT**:
After following the suggestion of  **twalberg**, I compiled it with GCC and NOT with cc, but now I'm getting this error doing the gmake:

```
...
ld: fatal: file ab.o: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
ld: fatal: file processing errors. No output written to ab

-----other times I get-----
ld: fatal: file /opt/pcre-8.30/lib/libpcre.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
ld: fatal: file processing errors. No output written to httpd
NOTE: I installed prce with (and without) the path to PATH=/usr/sfw/lib/64

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [ab] Error 1
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/build_src/source_apache_openssl/httpd-2.4.2/support'
gmake[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/build_src/source_apache_openssl/httpd-2.4.2/support'
gmake: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: The problem is you're using Solaris.

Comment: It should be possible to compile it in Solaris, and well, I'm not a Solaris fan, but where I work is Solaris only :/

Comment: You might need to use `gcc`, though, not `cc`...

Comment: @twalberg thanks. With GCC at least it pass the ./configure, but now I'm getting new errors in **gmake**

Comment: Looks like you're mixing 32-bit and 64-bit compiles somehow. That's not generally going to work out. In this case, `ab.o` is 32-bit, but the other stuff it's being linked to is 64-bit.

Comment: what could I do to solve this??? Years back -many years-, somebody installed apache 2.X.X here, in the x86-64. Maybe is a tweak of this version of apache?? any possible solution in your experience??, pelase

Answer (score 3):

Thank you **twalberg**, you gave light in this.

I had to compile everything with the -m64 flag.

I will put the mini-script I used. I hope that, if others have a similar problem, this could help you:

```
#!/bin/sh

#####################apacheInstaller####################################
# by: kani
# Pre-requisites:
# You must download and install in THIS ORDER:
#
# pcre-8.30 (ftp://ftp.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/software/programming/pcre)
# openssl-1.0.1c (http://www.openssl.org)
# apr-1.4.6
# apr-util-1.4.1
# httpd-2.4.2 (apache)
#
# I gathered all the files in:
#     /opt/build_src/source_apache_openssl/DIRECTORIES
#
# NOTE: this was done in a Solaris 10 x86-64 bit machine!
#
# HOW TO: execute the script
# chmod u+x apacheInstaller.sh
# source ./apacheInstaller.sh 
# NOTE: source is used for the export of the ENV variables!
#######################################################################

#Set ENV variables
export LDFLAGS=" -L/usr/sfw/lib -R/usr/sfw/lib -L/usr/X/lib -R/usr/X/lib -L/usr/X11/lib -R/usr/X11/lib -L/usr/ccs/lib -R/usr/ccs/lib "
export     PATH=/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sfw/bin:/usr/sfw/sbin:/usr/ccs/bin/amd64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:/usr/sfw/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH_64=/usr/lib/64:/usr/sfw/lib/64
#Dont use CC, use GCC! This is VERY important. It wont work otherwise!!
export CC=gcc
export CFLAGS=-m64 -O3
export CPP_FLAGS=-m64 -O3

#also used:
#export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/64:/usr/sfw/lib/64
#but not sure if this is needed. Maybe LD_LIBRARY_PATH_64 is enough?

#Install PCRE
#The -m64 flag is FUNDAMENTAL!!! Not sure about the others
cd /opt/build_src/source_apache_openssl/pcre-8.30
./configure --disable-cpp CFLAGS="-g -O3" CC="gcc -m64" --prefix=/opt/pcre-8.30
gmake clean
gmake
gmake install

#Install OPENSSL
cd /opt/build_src/source_apache_openssl/openssl-1.0.1c
./config --prefix=/opt/openssl-1.0.1c thread shared solaris64-gcc -m32
gmake clean
gmake
gmake install

#Install ARP
cd /opt/build_src/source_apache_openssl/apr-1.4.6
./configure --prefix=/opt/apr-1.4.6 --with-gnu-ld --enable-threads
gmake clean
gmake
gmake install

#Install ARP-UTIL
cd /opt/build_src/source_apache_openssl/apr-util-1.4.1
./configure --prefix=/opt/apr-util-1.4.1 --with-openssl=/opt/openssl-1.0.1c --with-  apr=/opt/apr-1.4.6 --with-crypto --enable-threads 
gmake clean
gmake
gmake install

#Install Apache. THE HOT PART!!
cd /opt/build_src/source_apache_openssl/httpd-2.4.2
./configure --prefix=/opt/httpd-2.4.2 --enable-so --enable-pie --enable-module=all --enable-mods-shared=all --enable-proxy --enable-proxy-connect --enable-proxy-ftp --enable-proxy-http --enable-proxy-ajp --enable-proxy-balancer --enable-ssl --with-ssl=/opt/openssl-1.0.1c --enable-static-support --enable-static-htpasswd --enable-static-htdigest --enable-static-rotatelogs --enable-static-logresolve --enable-cgi --enable-vhost --enable-imagemap --with-mpm=prefork --with-pcre=/opt/pcre-8.30 --with-apr=/opt/apr-1.4.6 --with-apr-util=/opt/apr-util-1.4.1
gmake clean
gmake
gmake install
```