# Compile Apache 2.4.6 in Solaris 10 in a SPARC machine (64bits) errors

Tags: apache, sparc, solaris-10

I've been compiling Httpd 2.4.6 in Solaris 10 in a SPARC machine from last Monday. I get some errors that I have no idea how to fix.

I've successfully compile the Httpd 2.4.6 in Solaris 10 x86, according this article:
[Compile Apache 2.4.2 in Solaris 10 in a x86 machine (64bits) errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548943/compile-apache-2-4-2-in-solaris-10-in-a-x86-machine-64bits-errors)

I tried several compiler flags, which failed with different errors. 
Here is the steps how I did the build:

```
export PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/sfw/bin:/usr/sfw/sbin:/usr/ccs/bin
#export LDFLAGS=" -L/usr/sfw/lib -R/usr/sfw/lib -L/usr/X/lib -R/usr/X/lib -L/usr/X11/lib -R/usr/X11/lib -L/usr/ccs/lib -R/usr/ccs/lib "
#export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/sfw/lib/sparcv9 -L/usr/lib/sparcv9 -L/usr/sfw/lib -R/usr/sfw/lib -L/usr/X/lib -R/usr/X/lib -L/usr/X11/lib -R/usr/X11/lib -L/usr/ccs/lib -R/usr/ccs/lib "
#export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib -R/usr/local/lib -R/usr/lib -L/usr/lib -R/usr/openwin/lib -L/usr/openwin/lib -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -R/usr/local/ssl/lib -L/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.2/lib -R/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.2/lib -L/usr/sfw/lib/sparcv9 -L/usr/lib/sparcv9 -L/usr/sfw/lib -R/usr/sfw/lib -L/usr/X/lib -R/usr/X/lib -L/usr/X11/lib -R/usr/X11/lib -L/usr/ccs/lib -R/usr/ccs/lib "
#export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:/usr/sfw/lib
#export LD_LIBRARY_PATH_64=/usr/lib/64:/usr/sfw/lib/64
#Dont use CC, use GCC! This is VERY important. It wont work otherwise!!
export CC=gcc
#export CFLAGS="-m64 -O3"
export CFLAGS="-m64 -O2 -L/usr/local/lib -R/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -R/usr/local/ssl/lib -L/usr/openwin/lib -R/usr/openwin/lib -I/usr/local/rrdtool-1.2.19/include -I/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.7/include -I/usr/local/include/cairo"
export CPPFLAGS="-m64 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/ssl/include -I/usr/local/include/ncurses -I/usr/openwin/include -I/usr/local/rrdtool-1.2.19/include -I/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.7/include -I/usr/local/include/lzo"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib -R/usr/local/lib -R/usr/lib -L/usr/lib -R/usr/openwin/lib -L/usr/openwin/lib -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -R/usr/local/ssl/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib -R/usr/X11R6/lib -L/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.7/lib -R/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.7/lib"
#export CFLAGS=” -O2 -mcpu=v9 -m64″
#export CPP_FLAGS="-m64 -O3"
#export CPP_FLAGS="-m64 -O3 -I/usr/sfw/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/ssl/include -I/usr/local/include/ncurses -I/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.2/include -I/usr/openwin/include"
#export CPP_FLAGS="-I/usr/sfw/include"
#export CXX_FLAGS="-m64 -O3"

bzip2 -dc apr-1.4.8.tar.bz2 | tar xf -
bzip2 -dc apr-util-1.5.2.tar.bz2 | tar xf -
bzip2 -dc httpd-2.4.6.tar.bz2.tar.bz2.tar.bz2 | tar xf -
mv apr-util-1.5.2/ httpd-2.4.6/srclib/apr-util
mv apr-1.4.8/ httpd-2.4.6/srclib/apr


gzip -dc m4-1.4.17.tar.gz | tar xf -
cd m4-1.4.17
./configure --prefix=/opt/cmtools/m4-1.4.17
gmake
gmake install
gmake clean

gzip -dc autoconf-2.69.tar.gz | tar xf -
cd autoconf-2.69
./configure --prefix=/opt/cmtools/autoconf-2.69 M4=/opt/cmtools/m4-1.4.17/bin/m4
gmake
gmake install
gmake clean


gzip -dc automake-1.13.2.tar.gz | tar xf -
cd automake-1.13.2 
./configure --prefix=/opt/cmtools/automake-1.13.2 PATH=/opt/cmtools/autoconf-2.69/bin:$PATH
gmake
gmake install
gmake clean


bzip2 -dc pcre-8.33.tar.bz2 | tar xf -
cd pcre-8.33/
./configure --disable-cpp CFLAGS="-g -O3" CC="gcc -m64" --prefix=/usr/local/pcre 
gmake
gmake install
gmake clean


gzip -dc openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz | tar xf -
cd openssl-1.0.1e
./config --prefix=/usr/local/ssl shared -m32
gmake
gmake install
gmake clean


bzip2 -dc binutils-2.23.2.tar.bz2.tar.bz2.tar.bz2 | tar xf -
cd binutils-2.23.2
./configure --prefix=/opt/cmtools/binutils-2.23.2
gmake
gmake install
gmake clean

cd httpd-2.4.6

./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 \
--enable-mods-shared=all \
--enable-proxy \
--enable-proxy-connect \
--enable-proxy-ftp \
--enable-proxy-http \
--enable-ssl=shared \
--enable-ssl \
--with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl \
--with-mpm=prefork --with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre \
-with-included-apr 

gmake
gmake install
gmake clean
```

The main error that I encountered when tried with different compile flags are:

```
ld: fatal: file /usr/local/lib/libpcre.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
ld: fatal: File processing errors. No output written to .libs/httpd
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[1]: *** [httpd] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/cmtools/soft/httpd-2.4.6'
gmake: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

ld: fatal: file /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
ld: fatal: file /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
ld: fatal: File processing errors. No output written to .libs/ab
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [ab] Error 1
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/cmtools/soft/httpd-2.4.6/support'
gmake[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/cmtools/soft/httpd-2.4.6/support'
gmake: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
TLSv1_2_client_method               ab.o
TLSv1_1_client_method               ab.o
BIO_set_callback                    ab.o
BIO_set_callback_arg                ab.o
BIO_get_callback_arg                ab.o
SSL_CTX_set_info_callback           ab.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to .libs/ab
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [ab] Error 1
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/cmtools/soft/httpd-2.4.6/support'
gmake[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/cmtools/soft/httpd-2.4.6/support'
gmake: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Here is the system info:

```
bash-3.00# uname -a
SunOS hegel 5.10 Generic_142909-17 sun4v sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise-T5120
bash-3.00# cat /etc/release 
                   Oracle Solaris 10 9/10 s10s_u9wos_14a SPARC
     Copyright (c) 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
                            Assembled 11 August 2010
bash-3.00# isainfo -b
64
```

Appreciated for any thread for this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You're building PCRE as a 64-bit library ("-m64"), but trying to build OpenSSL as a 32-bit library ("-m32") and link against that PCRE. That won't work.

Try building OpenSSL as 64-bit.

You may find that you need to edit the OpenSSL "Configure" file to adjust the compiler flags used for your hardware and compiler combination. For instance, if building on Solaris x86 using the Sun Studio compiler, the Configure script includes the "-fast" compiler flag. I found out the hard way that this hurts you when you build on a box with an AMD processor, but plan to use the code on boxes with Intel processors: the "-fast" flag enables all applicable optimizations for your compile box, including things like AMD 3DNow! extensions. Better to edit the Configure file before running it, and substitute "-fast" with architecture optimizations that are sensible for your lowest-common-denominator Intel systems in that case. OpenSSL uses an unusual Configure script that ignores the usual environment variables like CFLAGS, so editing Configure is occasionally necessary.

Also, don't be tempted to do a parallel make ("gmake -j *n*") with OpenSSL. The Makefile generated by OpenSSL's Configure isn't parallel-safe, and it won't build.